# Android: Saving data safely when service stops

Tags: android, service

I have a service bound to an activity. The service is set to stop with the task. I want to save some data to a file when this service stops. I have written a function to save data and call this function in `onDestroy()`, `onLowMemory()`, `onTaskRemoved()`.
Here is the code -

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
     saveData();
     super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 }

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    saveData();
    super.onLowMemory();
 }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  saveData();
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

But none of this method is called when user clears the app from recent apps list. In that case the service stops but my data is not written to a file.

Is there any way I can ensure data is written to file in every possible scenario?

Comment: Save it as you go, as the data changes. Your process can be terminated at any time, for any reason. Anything held in memory is only a cache.

Comment: @CommonsWare The data is changing regularly. Won't File I/O each time data is changed, will consume a lot of system resource?

Comment: You are certainly welcome to buffer the data if you want. Anything you have buffered and not yet persisted will be lost when your process is terminated. So, you have to strike a balance between frequency of data updates, frequency of disk I/O, and the risk of data loss.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data after user cleared cache from apps list, you need to save your data inside sqlite db or realm etc. Otherwise the data will be deleted.